# Cannot get the value from a search input

Tags: javascript, html, search

I created a website that connects to an API and uses the movie info. The problem is that I cannot add to a variable the input I add on the the search bar in order to use it as queue in the link and get the appropriate results.

I have tried to use every method possible in order to get the value from the input but I might be missing something.

```
<form action="search.php" class="search-form" name="fetch">
  <input type="text" id="term" placeholder="Search Movies..." required>
  <button type="button" onclick="getMovie()"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> 
  </button>
</form>

<script src="js/searchMov.js"></script>



$(function getMovie() {
    var query = document.getElementById("term").value;
}
```

I expect the value of the search input.

Comment: This is the message I am getting :                                                        
    movsearch.js:21 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of null
    at HTMLDocument.getMovie (movsearch.js:21)
    at j (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)

Comment: remove `$(` from your code

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Jquery the right way to do this is like

```js
  $(function(){  
  $('#getMovie').click(function(){
     var query =$('#term').val();
    console.log(query);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="search.php" class="search-form" name="fetch">
  <input type="text" id="term" placeholder="Search Movies..." required>
  <button type="button" id="getMovie"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> 
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I thought this would work too but it never goes through the   $('#getMovie').click(function() and I cannot understand why.